# KSOAP2 WebService errors running on Android Emulator

Tags: android, web-services, wsdl, ksoap2

I am trying to call a WSDL webservice running on local Tomcat server via Android Eclipse Emulator. I am using KSOAP2 to initiate service call.

The error I see when trying to get a response:

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'S:Client' faultstring: 'Cannot find dispatch method for {http://localhost:8080/test/}getAllAvailableAssessments' faultactor: 'null' detail: null
```

Some things to note:

- I have given INTERNET permission to the application
- WebService is running fine if tested on soapUI
- I am able to see WSDL file given its URL to the emulator's browser

This is the class that calls webservice:

```
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://localhost:8080/test/";
private static String URL = "http://10.10.10.55:8080/testwebservices/WebServices/AssessmentListingService?wsdl";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "getAllAvailableAssessments";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://localhost:8080/test/getAllAvailableAssessments";

public static String getAllAvailableAssessments()
{
    String webServiceResult = "";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try
    {
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
        webServiceResult = response.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return webServiceResult;
}
```

And this is the wsdl file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:assessmentListing="http://localhost:8080/test/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" name="AssessmentListingService" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/test/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://localhost:8080/test/AssessmentListing/">
<wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <xsd:import namespace="http://localhost:8080/test/AssessmentListing/" schemaLocation="AssessmentListing.xsd"></xsd:import>
    </xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
<wsdl:message name="getAllAvailableAssessmentsRequest">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters"
        element="xsd:getAllAvailableAssessmentsRequest">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:message name="getAllAvailableAssessmentsResponse">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters"
        element="xsd:getAllAvailableAssessmentsResponse">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>
<wsdl:portType name="AssessmentListingService">
    <wsdl:operation name="getAllAvailableAssessments">
        <wsdl:input message="assessmentListing:getAllAvailableAssessmentsRequest"></wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="assessmentListing:getAllAvailableAssessmentsResponse"></wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>
<wsdl:binding name="AssessmentListingServicePortBinding"
    type="assessmentListing:AssessmentListingService">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="getAllAvailableAssessments">
        <soap:operation
            soapAction="http://localhost:8080/test/AssessmentListingService/getAllAvailableAssessments" />
        <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="AssessmentListingService">
    <wsdl:port name="AssessmentListingServicePort" binding="assessmentListing:AssessmentListingServicePortBinding">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/testwebservices/WebServices/AssessmentListingService" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you run your web-service locally and read the number after the two dots: "http://localhost:"NEW_NUMBERS"/test/getAllAvailableAssessments";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `SOAP_ACTION` variable does not have to follow `NAMESPACE + METHOD_NAME` pattern. These values could be anything, depending on the WSDL structure.

After comparing request XML from SoapUI with dumped request XML from KSOAP2 I saw a mismatch.

Particularly in this case, adding "Request" string at the end of the `SOAP_ACTION` variable solves the issue.

Hence,

```
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://localhost:8080/test/";
private static String URL = "http://10.10.10.55:8080/testwebservices/WebServices/AssessmentListingService?wsdl";
private static String METHOD_NAME = "getAllAvailableAssessments";
private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://localhost:8080/test/getAllAvailableAssessmentsRequest";
```